# Bootstrap popover and partial render - jquery .on()

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii, popover

I have a Yii application using the cgridview that uses ajax pagination. Common problem for people - when you paginate you lose binding with jquery. For example, my popovers stop working (among other things).

I have the popover function as:

```
$('.myclass').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    show: true,
    html: true
});
```

How can I rewrite this function using jquery .on() event handling ? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `selector` property of the popover to prebind them.

```
var popOverSettings = {
    trigger: 'hover',
    show: true,
    html: true,
    selector: '.myclass'
}

$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFBFt/)**

Comment: PSL this looks good and works, except the html no longer renders properly. Any ideas on that issue ?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or something to replicate the issue. Are the popover shown?

Comment: Works! So we have to use data-html="true" in the html. Thanks.

Comment: @lilbiscuit Yes that will work. Infact many of those attributes like even trigger which you know already can be data attributes like `data-trigger="hover"`

Comment: Any idea why it worked as a javascript attribute before, but not with this solution? It's not a big deal but it might be helpful to know.

Comment: @lilbiscuit most possibly your version of bootstrap has some issues. See it working here in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qAjEN/ It doesn't have other plugins though i just added BS alone inthe fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set up an ajaxComplete handler. This works for me:

```
// Enable popovers for Ajax content
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: 'hover', html: true }).click(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```